# What are the programming and computer references in Steins;Gate?

Tags: steins-gate

I want to know the programming and computer references present in Steins;Gate.

For example, I noticed the SQL database is referenced.

Answer (score 21):

[image: SQL book owned by Daru in Steins;Gate]

SQL is mentioned, as the question suggests. They even used company and trademarked names:

> MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, SQLite, Access, ANSI

Of particular interest is the fact that Oracle, the company that owns Java, is present. It's rare to find original trademarks in anime.

A book for "Goodle Endroid", a clear reference to Google Android, can also be seen:

[image: Goodle Endroid, SSH and other books owned by Daru]

A book on SSH, the protocol used for remote administration, is shown, as well as a book that mentions Unicode, JIS (essentially the Japanese equivalent of ASCII), Java, Ruby 1.8/1.9, and Windows:

[image: Unicode and SSH books]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation about answering your own questions has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38177/discussion-on-answer-by-wally-what-are-the-programming-and-computer-references-i).

Comment: Those two books looks like OReilly ones. I found one with [a similar bird sketch](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596809577.do#),

Comment: It's obviously meant to be an O'Relliy SSH book, but it's not the real O'Reilly SSH cover (pictured here in the JP edition: http://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/images/picture_large4-87311-287-7.jpeg )

Answer (score 11):

Aside from what's mentioned in Wally's answer, following programming and computer-related items appear:

IBN 5100, a clear expy of IBM 5100 that was featured in the original John Titor forum posts:
[image: IBN 5100]

@chanel textboard, very likely a reference to real-life 2channel:
[image]

Comment: @channel is indeed a reference to 2channel (hint: Shift key)

Comment: @AkiTanaka depends very much on the keyboard layout.

Comment: @Worse_Username What do you mean? Are there keyboards that don't output @ when Shift+2 is pressed?

Comment: @Wally: Most European keyboards have " on Shift-2, @ is shift-' e.g. on the UK layout: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#United_Kingdom

Answer (score 1):

I believe the company that they were fighting against,'SERN', is an obvious reference to the company CERN. SERN is known to operate the largest particle physics laboratory in the world, the same goes for the real CERN.

[image]

Comment: Just like John Titor actually *existed* (most likely as a made-up character, but still). But this isn't programming nor computer-related, and neither is SERN/CERN.